# SQL query from multiple table with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Using MySQL, I want to do all these in one insert:

> 1. table T1 contains column Ca & Cb. T1 is in database D1. Insert into table T1 specifying column Ca, Cb.
> 2. table T2 contains column C2. T2 is in database D2. Set T1.Ca's value with T2.C2
> 3. table T3 contains column C3 & C4. T3 is in database D2. use the T2.C2 value to query T3.C3 and use the C4 value of the same row to set T1.Cb

so I did:

```
insert into T1(Ca, Cb)
select C2
from D2.T2
union
select C4
from D2.T3
where C3=T2.C2;
```

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'T2.C2' in 'where clause'

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correcly you should use a join and not an union

```
   insert into D1.T1(Ca, Cb)
   select T2.C2, T3.C4
   from D2.T2 
   INNER JOIN D2.T3 on T2.C2 = T3.C3
```

the second select of the union don't know the content of the firts select  .. so you have the error

> Unknown column 'T2.C2' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Queries which are Unioned are independent of one another.
You want to join these tables.

```
select C2,C4
from D2.T2 a
INNER JOIN  D2.T3 b  ON b.C3=a.C2;
```